# kill a java process after it was running for one hour

Tags: ubuntu, process, java

I need a script that will murder java processes that have been on for more than one hour.

So I am trying this

```
timeout -k 10s nohup cpulimit -l 40 -- java -jar file.jar
```

Any idea why this isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

You should have the `nohup` first, then `timeout`. `nohup`'s disassociation with the controlling terminal breaks the ownership relationship that `timeout` uses to kill.

Also `10s` tells `timeout` "Ten Seconds", not "One Hour".